# Opening a pop up window automatically on the date mentioned in the function

Tags: javascript

I want to open a pop up window automatically (when I open my website) after a particular date that I mention in the function.

How can I assign date function? I want this window to be opened automatically on `27/07/2011` and after that whenever I open the website. Please suggest

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function newPopup(url) {
popupWindow = window.open(
           url,'popUpWindow','height=600,width=605,left=4,top=4,resizable=no,scrollbars=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=yes')
  }
    </script>
```

Comment: i think there is an error i your code. `newPopup("google.com";);` should be `newPopup("google.com");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function newPopup(url) {
      popupWindow = window.open(url,'popUpWindow','...');
    }

    var date = new Date();
    var formatedDate = date.getDate()+"/"+(date.getMonth()+1)+"/"+date.getFullYear();

    if (formatedDate == "27/07/2011 ") {
       newPopup("http://example.com");
    }
</script>
```

Make note that popup blockers will automatically block this window.
Most popup blockers only allow popups if they are triggered by the user, for example by a click.

Triggering the popup using on click event:

```
<a href="#" onclick="newPopup('http://example.com'); return false;">
     Click Here to open pop up window
</a>
```

when the user click on the link, the function newPopup is triggered and your popup opens.

Comment: Within the script do i need to include this code? sorry i am very new to javascript.

Comment: But it will not open automatically right?if i want to bypass pop up blockers , i have to use any triggerings i mean when user click on a button or text pop up should open . i can do like this right? please suggest.

Comment: @ ibi, i tried running this code by putting in my website i mean in html, within head i have placed this code. but nothing is happening. am i doing anything wrong? please help

Comment: See the last part of my answer for how it is done, in its simplest way

Comment: @priya no there is no error, today is not july 27th, change the date to today and test it

Comment: yes, thats what. if the date is 27th, pop up should not get open right? but it is opening here, eve if the date is 27th.

Comment: If you click on the button, the popup will open no matter what day it is. for automatically opening, the popup only open on the set date.

Comment: sorry for irritating. even if i change the date to today's and placed it in my web page, it doesnt open. please suggest

Comment: please help me. like thi i have placed the code within head 

    '<script type="text/javascript"> 
     function newPopup(url) {
      popupWindow = window.open(url,'popUpWindow','height=600,width=605,left=4,top=4,resizable=no,scrollbars=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=yes');
    }

    var date = new Date();
    var formatedDate = date.getDate()+"/"+(date.getMonth()+1)+"/"+date.getFullYear();

    if (formatedDate == "23/07/2011 ") {
       newPopup("http://google.com");
    }
   </script>'
still not opening automatically :(

Answer (score 0):

Make a new datetime object: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

Equal to 27/07/2011. Using: setDate, setDay, and setFullYear

Make another datetime equal to the current date: (you have to make this by using getDate, getDay, and getFullYear)

If the current date getTime() is > than the created date getTime() then execute your script. (This will be an if statement wrapped around your code.)

Set your function to activate on load by changing your html's body tag to:

This script should give you a good starting guide to playing with dateTime objects:
http://www.mediacollege.com/internet/javascript/date-time/

Good Luck!